# Can I apply an operator on a curried function so that its return type is unit without specifying the number of arguments?

Tags: f#

Given an arbitrary function `func` with arbitrary argument types and number I would like to get a function that returns a unit -- `func`with the return value ignored. Think of it as projection onto purely side-effecting functions. If `func` takes one argument (or if it is in an uncurried form) it is just `func>>ignore`. The obvious solution is to write a generic operator for every number of arguments of `func` that we need:

```
let inline unitise1 f a = f a |> ignore
let inline unitise2 f a b = f a b |> ignore
let inline unitise3 f a b c = f a b c |> ignore
let inline unitise4 f a b c d = f a b c d |> ignore
```

etc. That's messy and inconvenient because we need to count the arguments every time, and the code will not refactor well. Is there a language construct that I'm missing that would allow to do this cleaner?

EDIT: I believe such an operator would be useful because the `NET` generics are weaker than `F#` statically resolved type parameters. Here's what I mean. Suppose I have a higher order function

```
let inline higher f g =
    f 7 |> ignore
    g 3 |> ignore
```

We can pass to it any function whatsoever provided its first argument is an `int`. So this will work:

```
let add n = n+1
let str (n:int) = n.ToString()
higher add str
higher str add
```

In particular, no generic type annotations are needed. This is what we know and love about F#. Now, I have a situation were I need to pass a lot (~15) of functions as arguments for `higher`. They will will be passed down the call chain multiple times. It is natural to group them in a data structure.

```
type Funcs<'R1,'R2,'R3> = {f1:int->'R1;f2:int->'R2;f3:int->'R3}
```

This gets ugly well before you reach 15 generic parameters. Not type annotating was possible only when functions were concerned. If I could unitise functions I'd change `higher` to

```
let inline higher f g =
    f 7
    g 3
```

and would use a helper function that unitises every function before building `Funcs` from them. In this toy example `f` and `g` both have one argument so the solution is easy, but in the real case different functions have different numbers of arguments.

Since writing this questions I've gritted my teeth though and wrote a behemoth of `Funcs` with 15 generic parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want to do this. Even if you have such function, say `unitise`, using it still would be the same amount of work as using `ignore` when you're calling the function... Or do you have some other use case in mind?

Comment: @TomasPetricek I've added some details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@TomasPetricek is absolutely right, you can't build such a function. **Here's the proof.**

**Suppose**, you have created `unitise` function so that the following worked:

```
// just sample functions with 1, 2, and 3 curried arguments
let f1 a = a
let f2 a b = (a,b)
let f3 a b c = (a,b,c)

let x1 = unitise f1 5             // expected x1:unit
let x2 = unitise f2 5 42          // expected x2:unit
let x3 = unitise f3 5 "foobar" 42 // expected x3:unit
```

There is no generic for arbitrary number of curried arguments, so you have to compute `(f1 5)`, `(f2 5 42)`, etc prior to invocation of `unitise`:

```
let x1 = unitise (f1 5)             // expected x1:unit
let x2 = unitise (f2 5 42)          // expected x2:unit
let x3 = unitise (f3 5 "foobar" 42) // expected x3:unit
```

Hence, `unitise` becomes equivalent to `ignore`:

```
let x3 = ignore (f3 5 "foobar" 42) // expected x3:unit
```

If you'd like `ignore` (or `unitise`) to be placed in the very beginning of the statement and also avoiding parentheses for readability purposes, consider using a **high precedence, right associative backward pipe**, `(^<|)`:

```
let inline (^<|) f a = f a
```

Then your code will look like:

```
let x1 = ignore ^<| f1 5             // expected x1:unit
let x2 = ignore ^<| f2 5 42          // expected x2:unit
let x3 = ignore ^<| f3 5 "foobar" 42 // expected x3:unit
```

Comment: Thanks. I've realised it is impossible to do with a higher order function. That's why I asked about some language construct I may be missing. An example of that might be a symbol that captures all curried arguments and lets them be applied afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of such function is incoherent. Remember that in f# *there is no function with more than 1 argument*.

The function

```
let f a b = 0
```

is the same as

```
let f a = fun b -> 0
```

so it should be that

```
unitize f a b = ()
```

and

```
unitize f a = ()
```

which implies

```
() b = ()
```